# SQLite statement INSERT OR REPLACE INTO not clear to me

Tags: ios, sqlite

The SQLite statement `INSERT OR REPLACE INTO` replaces the row if it already exists. But when I run the same statement again and again, it keeps on inserting instead of replacing.

In what case does REPLACE actually occur?

```
INSERT OR REPLACE INTO names (rollno, name) VALUES (1, "Adam")
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The replace occurs if the row you want to insert has the same PRIMARY KEY as another in your table.
You probably forgot to define a primary key.

Comment: Or there is a primary key that is auto-increment (`id` or something) that you are not provinding in your query. It will get a new `id`, so it is never duplicate.

Answer (score 3):

Values will be replaced in some row if a `UNIQUE` violation occurs, as is explained in the [documentation](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_conflict.html):

> When a UNIQUE constraint violation occurs, the REPLACE algorithm
>   deletes pre-existing rows that are causing the constraint violation
>   prior to inserting or updating the current row and the command
>   continues executing normally. If a NOT NULL constraint violation
>   occurs, the REPLACE conflict resolution replaces the NULL value with
>   he default value for that column, or if the column has no default
>   value, then the ABORT algorithm is used. If a CHECK constraint
>   violation occurs, the REPLACE conflict resolution algorithm always
>   works like ABORT.

I presume that the column that you would to make `UNIQUE` is `rollno`. You can make it unique by making it the `PRIMARY KEY` of the table, or by simply creating a [`UNIQUE` constrain](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_createtable.html#uniqueconst) on it.

Answer (score 1):

Hahaha, oh man where do I begin?

I was cursing the computer when I went through this SQL hell.

Thankfully, I manage to get it working! :D

One thing I learned with the INSERT OR REPLACE INTO statement is you need to do one super critical thing:

```
Mark one column of your table as "UNIQUE" during SQL table creation.
```

Here's an example (**scroll to the right end**):

```
NSString *strEvents = @"CREATE TABLE Events (eventid INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, nodeID INTEGER, title VARCHAR(255), description TEXT, eventTime VARCHAR(255), eventDate VARCHAR(255), eventLocation VARCHAR(255), imagePaths TEXT, bookingURL TEXT, UNIQUE(nodeID));";
```

In the above example, I have marked my "nodeID" column as unique.

Once you do that, you can use it like so:

```
-(void)batchSaveEvents:(NSMutableArray *)paramList
{
    @synchronized(self)
    {
        if(self.isConnected == YES)
        {
            const char *sql = "INSERT OR REPLACE INTO Events (nodeID,title,description,eventTime,eventDate,eventLocation,imagePaths,bookingURL) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?);";

            sqlite3_stmt *stmtSave;

            if(sqlite3_prepare(objDatabase, sql, -1, &stmtSave, NULL) != SQLITE_OK)
            {
                //NSLog(@"FAILED %s", sqlite3_errmsg(objDatabase));

                return;
            }

            int listIndex = 0;        

            sqlite3_exec(objDatabase, "BEGIN IMMEDIATE TRANSACTION", 0, 0, 0); // Begin Trasaction

            for(listIndex = 0; listIndex < [paramList count]; listIndex++)
            {
                sqlite3_bind_int(stmtSave, 1, [[(Event *)[paramList objectAtIndex:listIndex] nodeID] intValue]);
                sqlite3_bind_text(stmtSave, 2, [[(Event *)[paramList objectAtIndex:listIndex] title] UTF8String], -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT);
                sqlite3_bind_text(stmtSave, 3, [[(Event *)[paramList objectAtIndex:listIndex] description] UTF8String], -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT);
                sqlite3_bind_text(stmtSave, 4, [[(Event *)[paramList objectAtIndex:listIndex] eventTime] UTF8String], -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT);
                sqlite3_bind_text(stmtSave, 5, [[(Event *)[paramList objectAtIndex:listIndex] eventDate] UTF8String], -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT);
                sqlite3_bind_text(stmtSave, 6, [[(Event *)[paramList objectAtIndex:listIndex] eventLocation] UTF8String], -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT);

                sqlite3_bind_text(stmtSave, 7, [[(Event *)[paramList objectAtIndex:listIndex] imagePaths] UTF8String], -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT);

                sqlite3_bind_text(stmtSave, 8, [[(Event *)[paramList objectAtIndex:listIndex] bookingURL] UTF8String], -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT);

                sqlite3_step(stmtSave);
                sqlite3_reset(stmtSave);
            }

            sqlite3_exec(objDatabase, "COMMIT", 0, 0, 0); // Commit Transaction

            sqlite3_finalize(stmtSave);
        }
    }
}
```

Good luck brudda! ... or sista!